# Should WatchService be blocking on register?

Tags: java, watchservice

I'm working with a user of my software who is experiencing a problem when my software adds a watch for a folder. The call to `register` appears to block forever. Here's a thread dump from the user's machine:

```
platformExecutor [01-12_10:14]" Id=56 WAITING on sun.nio.fs.AbstractPoller$Request@1492d01
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    -  waiting on sun.nio.fs.AbstractPoller$Request@1492d01
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.fs.AbstractPoller$Request.awaitResult(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.fs.AbstractPoller.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.fs.AbstractPoller.register(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsWatchService.register(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPath.register(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.fs.AbstractPath.register(Unknown Source)
    at com.elsten.bliss.platform.storage.file.observer.filewatcher.FileWatcherFileSystemObserver$WatchingFileVisitor$$anonfun$preVisitDirectory$2.apply(FileWatcherFileSystemObserver.scala:87)
```

We left it several hours, and the call to `register` did not return.

The folder being watched is accessed across a network on network attached storage, using wifi. I realise this is less reliable, but I have many users with a similar configuration and this is the first time this has been reported.

In the Javadocs for `register` there's no mention of the potential for blocking. Should I actually surround this call in a timeout of some kind?

Comment: I'm seeing this exact same problem.  In my case I'm watching a directory on the local filesystem (not network-attached), and my unit tests intermittently hang with the exact same stack trace you show.  I left it there for two days and it's still hung.  I would definitely call this a bug.

Comment: I opened a ticket with Oracle support, including a reproducible test case.

Comment: Interesting, please post the URL if/when you get a proper bug ID. Is this with Oracle or OpenJDK?

Comment: Yeah I'll post a bug id if I get it.  It's with Oracle.

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem, and found no solution at all after searching for hours.

Comment: This seems like a JDK bug in Windows. See the links [from Openjdk Mailing list](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/nio-dev/2016-April/003632.html) and [MSDN](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20110303-00/?p=11313) about this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for all for who commented.

[It looks like this is a bug](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8153925), and is fixed in 8u152 (just released) and Java 9.